# Frida hook final native

Tags: javascript, java, frida

I have this Java code:

```
final String b() throws Exception {}
    .....
    return v0;

public final void b(Application arg6) {}
```

How I can get the return value of the first function?
This is my javascript code, I hooked it with frida but it not work.

```
testfunction: function () {
    Java.perform(function () {
        var encrypter = Java.use("es");
        return encrypter.b();
        });
    },
```

Anyone can tell my how i can solve this. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

When you define an export, you don't have to overload the method. For example, in your situation:

```
rpc.exports = {
  testfunction: function () {
    Java.perform(function() {
      var es_class = Java.use("es");
      return es_class.b();
    });
  }
}
```

Additionally, check if your function (testfunction) is inside the rpc.export section.

Let me know if this solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code is not hooking anything. To hook a function, you need to override its implementation as follows:

```
Java.perform(function () {
    var encrypter = Java.use("es");
    // Overload needed because two 'b' functions exist:
    var b = encrypter.b.overload();
    b.implementation = function() {
        const retVal = b.call(this);
        console.log("hook succeeded! Return value: " + retVal);
        return retVal;
    };
});
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://www.frida.re/docs/javascript-api/) and this [cheat sheet](https://awakened1712.github.io/hacking/hacking-frida/) for more common examples.